# Update many-to-many association in rails (User-Team relationship aka Membership)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, associations

I just created a create feature for adding a team together with adding the members to a said team.

The form contains the following:

1. Name of the team.
2. Team's department.
3. Leader (value is the user id, but displayed as full name)
4. Members (values are user ids, but displayed also as full names) //I used a special select menu called select2.

Here are the models. I'll only show the associations and some methods related to my problem.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :teams, through: :memberships

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, :teams
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :teams, through: :memberships

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, :users

    def build_membership(user_ids)
        unless user_ids.blank?
            user_ids.each do |id|   
                self.users << User.find_by_id(id)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :user

    #Note that leader and members are both users
end
```

Here is the controller, with the create and update methods.

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @team = Team.new(team_params)
        @team.build_membership(build_members_array(members_params))

        if @team.save
            flash.now[:success] = 'Team was successfully created.'
            redirect_to @team
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = @team.errors.full_messages
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def update
        # TO-DO: update leader and members (i.e. add or remove member)
        if @team.update(team_params)
            flash.now[:success] = "Team was successfully updated."
            redirect_to @team
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = @team.errors.full_messages
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    private
        def team_params
            params.require(:team).permit(:name,:department)
        end

        def members_params
            params.require(:team).permit(:leader, members:[])
        end

        def build_user_ids_array(members)
            #put ids of leader and members in an array
        end
end
```

It seems that only the name and department attributes are only updated while the leader and the members are not. Should I create my own method again for updating the roster of the team or do something else in mind?

Answer (score 0):

`@team.build_membership` would be if you are passing in the params to create a new user, but you are using existing `User`'s so this wouldn't apply. You will want to instead fetch all of the `User`'s by their `id` and then add that the the `Team`.  You also need to permit the `id` in the `members_attributes` in your `member_params` method.
Something like:

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)
    @team.memberships << users_from_params

    if @team.save
        flash.now[:success] = 'Team was successfully created.'
        redirect_to @team
    else
        flash.now[:notice] = @team.errors.full_messages
        render "new"
    end
end

def members_params
   params.require(:team).permit(:leader, members_attributes: [:id])
end

def users_from_params
  #This members_params[:members_attributes].values should be an array of `id`s
  User.find(members_params[:members_attributes].values)
end
```

Comment: does the same applies for the update method? (see TO-DO)

Comment: Yea it looks like it should be the same

Comment: will it automatically replace the members just by doing so? because I noticed that it just only adds as duplicates just by, for example, replacing a member with a new one (btw, i already did an error handling for that).

Comment: Sorry idk what I was thinking. It wouldn't remove them. You would have to check and delete the ones not included I think

Comment: ActiveRecord will expose a membership_ids accessor. If you set that explicitly and call save it will update it properly